# Sink is not written into delta table in Spark structured streaming

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I want to create a streaming job, that reads messages from a folder within TXT files, does the parsing, some processing, and appends the result into one of 3 possible delta tables depending on the parse result. There is a parse_failed table, an unknwon_msgs table, and a parsed_msgs table.

Reading is done with

```py
sdf = spark.readStream.text(path=path_input, lineSep="\n\n", pathGlobFilter="*.txt", recursiveFileLookup=True)
```

and writing with

```py
x = sdf.writeStream.foreachBatch(process_microbatch).start()
```

where process_microbatch is

```py
def process_microbatch(self, batch_df: DataFrame, batch_id: int) -> None:
    """Processing of newly arrived messages. For each message replicate it if needed, and execute the parse_msg_proxy on each."""
    batch_df.rdd.flatMap(lambda msg: replicate_msg(msg)).map(lambda msg: parse_msg_proxy(msg))
```

and where parse_msg_proxy is

```py
def parse_msg_proxy(self, msg: str) -> None:
        try:
            parsed_msg = parse_message(msg, element_mapping)
            # do some processing
            # create df_msg dataframe from parsed_msg
            df_msg.write.format("delta").mode("append").save(path_parsed_msgs)
        except ParseException as e:
            spark.createDataFrame([{'msg': parsed_msg, 'error': str(e)}]).write.format("delta").mode("append").save(path_parse_errors)
            raise Exception("Parse error occured.")
        except UnknownMsgTypeException:
            spark.createDataFrame([{'msg': parsed_msg}]).write.format("delta").mode("append").save(path_unknown_msgs)
```

The streaming job starts without error message, but the delta tables are not created. Whats wrong?

Thanks!

Update:

If I change the function to be executed by adding a collect to it:

```py
def process_microbatch(self, batch_df: DataFrame, batch_id: int) -> None:
    """Processing of newly arrived messages. For each message replicate it if needed, and execute the parse_msg_proxy on each."""
    batch_df.rdd.flatMap(lambda msg: replicate_msg(msg)).map(lambda msg: parse_msg_proxy(msg)).collect()
```

I get the error message
*RuntimeError: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.*

Comment: Do your spark application shut down without any error or just hang there and process nothing?

Comment: It just hangs, and processes nothing.